# How to choose the best Linux distro depending on your hardware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distributions, lubuntu

I have a centrino 1.7 GHz with 512 RAM. It is an old computer.

I tried to google for something that could ease my chose for a good linux distro that would run smooth on that computer and still being pretty and easy to work.

I thought on Lubuntu, but I found so many others (gOS, EeeXubuntu, Ubuntu Netbook Remix, Puppy...).

Not to mention the biggest mainstream distros that could, or couldn't, run smooth in it...

Is there a place where I can have this kind of advise based on hardware and personal preferences?

What would you suggest to my case?

Thank you!

Comment: We don't consider asking for recommendations on topic, sorry. See the list of answers which all recommend a specific distribution rather than the process of finding ong – this is not encouraged. There have been similar questions on this site already. The best would probably be to try for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your old computer (or any old computer), you should try [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/). It is altogether 50 MB (which is crazy small) and requires only 16 MB of RAM.

I do not know of any smaller distro that gives you all of the features that this one does.

Hope this helps (if it does, please confirm my answer).

Comment: Puppy is another good choice, its weird that the user states it would not run smoothly.

Comment: @AthomSfere - OP did not say that Puppy ***did not*** run smoothly *'...distros that **could, or couldn't**, run smooth in it...'*. OP asking for help to narrow the big list down to those that will run smoothly with limited resources. I'm sure they'll appreciate your recommendation of Puppy.

Comment: @KevinFegan Never mind then, I mis-read. DSL and Puppy should both make great chocies then

Answer (score 0):

I think Ubuntu with Xfce will fit.

You can download it from:

http://xubuntu.org/

Comment: you do not need to sign your post (In fact its done automatically).

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling froggy and brave, installing a base Arch Linux system with basic networking and a minimalist window manager has worked great for my low spec systems.

This doesn't fall under the "easy" category you are looking for but you will learn a lot as an added bonus and your low specs will thank you once all is configured.